# Convergence with probability one and convergence in law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Suppose $\sqrt{n}(X_n - \mu)\overset{d}{\longrightarrow}N\left(0,\sigma^2\right)$. Prove that $X_n \overset{p}{\longrightarrow}\mu$ is true.

I see that it's not true in general and I can construct a few examples when convergence in distribution does not imply convergence with probability one. But how to approach this problem?

Comment: Decency dictates you put in at least some effort before asking someone to do your homework for you...

Comment: I see that it's not true in general and I can construct a few examples when convergence in distribution does not imply convergence with probability one. But how to approach this problem?

Comment: I edit my answer. Please see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $X_n$~$N(\mu,\frac{\sigma ^2}{n})$.Here I assume that $\sigma$ is known. 
Note that
 $$\begin{align} P[|X_n-\mu|<\epsilon] &= P[-\epsilon<X_n-\mu<\epsilon] \\ &= P[-\frac{\epsilon\sqrt n}{\sigma} <\frac{\sqrt n(X_n-\mu)}{\sigma}<\frac{\epsilon\sqrt n}{\sigma}] \\ &= 2 \Phi(\frac{\epsilon\sqrt n}{\sigma})-1  \to 1 ~ as ~n \to \infty\end{align}$$ So,$X_n \overset{p}{\longrightarrow}\mu$ is true.

I think your conclution is wrong.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!

Comment: $2 \Phi\left(\dfrac{\epsilon\sqrt n}{\sigma}\right)-1  \to 1$

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks.

Comment: @Learner: You are right. So, I edit my answer.